# Capillary action for isotope separation

Tags: ions, isotopes, capillary-action

Take, for example, D2O and H2O. As they have different densities, they should have a different maximum capillary height *h*, where *h* is defined according to [Jurin's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurin%27s_law). Then, each isotope of D and H would be in molecules that have a different maximum capillary height and can thereby be separated.

Can a similar method be used for the separation of ionic isotopes in a solution, where each isotope ion will have a different maximum height *h*? Even if the height differences are very small, I believe a certain degree of enrichment may be possible.

My research suggests that there are some implementations of ["Isotope Enrichment Using
Microchannel Distillation
Technology"](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/1526733) at [PNNL](https://www.pnnl.gov/), as well as isotope fractionation being reported using capillary forces, but they do not necessarily use the maximum height differences between liquids or solutions of different densities.